# flask wtforms validate_on_submit

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a basic form and my `validate_on_submit()` function is not coming true.
It only returns `nahh` as you can see it in my routes.
Can anyone help find what's wrong with my codes.

Validation:-

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators = [
        InputRequired(message = "Please Enter the username"),
        Length(min = 2, max = 23)
        ])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators = [
        InputRequired(),
        Length(min = 4, max = 25, message="Password must be between 4 and 25 characters")
        ])
```

Routes:-

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        print(username)
        return username
    return render_template('login.html', form = form)
    
@app.route('/loginn', methods=['POST'])
def loginn():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return "Succeeds"
    else:
        return "Naahh"
```

Login.html:-

```
<body>
<form action="/loginn" method="POST">
    Username
  {% if form.username.errors %}
            {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
              {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
              {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
            {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}

            {% endif %}
              Password
              {% if form.password.errors %}
            {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
              {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
              {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
            {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}

            {% endif %}
            <button>Submit</button>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF token is missing in the login.html file